# Passing a web service an unknown number of parameters

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json, serialization

I'm relatively new to utilizing web services.  I'm trying to create one that will be accepting data from a ASP.Net form whose input controls are created dynamically at runtime and I don't how many control values will be getting passed.

I'm thinking I'll be using jQuery's serialize() on the form to get the data, but what do I have the web service accept for a parameter?  I thought maybe I could use serializeArray(), but still I don't know what type of variable to accept for the JavaScript array.

Finally, I was thinking that I might need to create a simple data transfer object with the data before sending it along to the web service.  I just didn't wanna go through with the DTO route if there was a much simpler way or an established best practice that I should follow.

Thanks in advance for any direction you can provide and let me know I wasn't clear enough, or if you have any questions.

Comment: I am probably not understanding your architecture correctly, but it sounds as if you have complete control over the ASP.Net form that will be passing input values to the web service.  If this is the case, why do you need a separate web service at all?

Comment: I have server processing that is required as part of the input validation.  There are special validation rules dependent on details placed into the control ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I went with creating my own data transfer object which I guess was always the front of brain solution, I was just thinking that there was probably a recognized best practice on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the headline question (assuming this is an ASP.Net web service) is to use the `params` keyword in your web service method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void SendSomething(params string[] somethings)
{
    foreach (string s in somethings)
    {
        // do whatever you're gonna do
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
SendSomething("whatever");
SendSomething("whatever 1", "whatever 2", "whatever 3");
```

In fact, you don't really even need the `params` keyword - using an ordinary array as a parameter will let you pass in an unknown number of values.

Comment: I need the control ID and the value as a key value pair, so I'm trying to pass the JSON string of the form using var postData = $('#aspnetForm').serializeArray(); and then $.ajax({  data: JSON.stringify(postData).  And setting the web service to accept a string array errorred with "Type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, ... is not supported for deserialization of an array.".  So I thought I probably needed a multi-dimensional array and changed the web service's parameter to string[,] and still received the same exception.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you're trying to call the web service from the client page via AJAX? Is the form too large to do a regular postback?

Comment: You are correct. I am trying to not do a postback since this is basically, a more complex input validation, but to the user, still just input validation.

Comment: Your problem is probably in the way you're calling the web service from AJAX, then. Whenever a C# client calls a web service, the serialization/deserializition grisliness is completely hidden, and you can pass in arrays of objects or almost anything (even List<string>) as parameters. I'm pretty sure you can also pass string[], but maybe try defining your web service method to take object[] and see what that does.

Comment: Oop, this may be simpler than I thought. In the code in your first comment here, it looks like you're trying to call serializeArray() on something that is just a single string (i.e. not a string *array*).

Comment: I'm calling jQuery's serializeArray() on the entire ASP.Net form.

Comment: I don't know AJAX or JQuery at all, but it looks like JSON.stringify returns just a single string, so your web service method should be defined to take a string, not a string *array*. You'll then have to parse that string (to get out the key/value pairs) inside the web service method.